# Mahout's OnlineLogisticRegression classifier consistently produces 100% classification probability indices

Tags: java, classification, regression, mahout

Classified probability vectors always end up looking like (0, 0, 1, 0) or (1, 0, 0, 0) - indicating that one category is 100% probable and the others are zero. This is fine since they should add up to 1, but I'm curious as to why it consistently spits out 100% probabilities across thousands of testing examples (I have never seen it do anything otherwise).

Here's the gist of my implementation:

```
OnlineLogisticRegression model = new OnlineLogisticRegression(4, 3, new L2());
Vector v = new RandomAccessSparseVector(3);  //size representing # features
FeatureVectorEncoder feature1Encoder = new ContinuousValueEncoder("feature1Encoder"); 
//so on for the remaining two encoders (feature 2 and 3)

for(int i: predictors) {  //where predictors is some array of continuous values representing the first feature
    feature1Encoder.addToVector(null, i, v); //passing null for originalForm string (not necessary for continuous encoding)
}
//so on for the remaining two features

for(int i: targets) {  //where targets is an int array that represents the different categories, achieved through interning via Dictionary
   model.train(i, v);  //train the model by passing the vector's actual classification. In the current application, it's possible for a vector to have multiple classifications. I thought this may be where the problem was, so I tried only training one category instead of looping through all of the categories the vector could be classified into, but to no avail.
}

Vector probabilities = model.classifyFull(someNewTestVector); //this vector will consistently look like (0, 1, 0, 0)
```